# How to Generate URL depending on user click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have React App that loads a component

```
<Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
```

Assuming Dashboard renders a Ag Grid Table. (Complex Objects table sample in the this sample https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-set-tree-list/)

For now, I have to share a link to anyone like : https://localhost:3000/dashboard and ask user to navigate  to Erica Rogers --> Luke McBride --> Paul Smith to get details of Paul Smith

Instead is it possible to generate url like https://localhost:3000/dashboard/EricaRogers/LukeMcBride (or something similar) so that I can just share this link?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you probably want to use URL variables. and then according to them, you can show/hide table data.

Comment: @aktoriukas I am not sure what do you mean by using variable and show/hide table. This is just one component. I have several components rendering different table on diff page.

Comment: url variable looks something like this `https://website.com/table?openData=4`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not very hot on React, but here is a working example in Angular:

https://plnkr.co/edit/FD3kwGSIqpvQIpco?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #grid
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef"
    [treeData]="true"
    [animateRows]="true"
    [groupDefaultExpanded]="groupDefaultExpanded"
    [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
    (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered()"
    [rowData]="rowData"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Use the firstDataRendered() method to find the item you want and select it

```
onFirstDataRendered() {
    // Find the person from the query string
    // Here, pretend it's Paul Smith
    const personToHightlight = "PaulSmith";
    this.grid.api.forEachNode(node =>{
      // Find the item you want to highlight
      if (node.data.path.displayValue.replace(' ', '') == 'PaulSmith'){
        node.setSelected(true, true, true)
        this.grid.api.ensureNodeVisible(node, 'middle')
      }
    })
  }
```

This loops through the nodes and finds the one you want.  It sets it to be selected and then scrolls the grid to the correct place (ensureNodeVisible).

If the tree structure changes and Paul Smith moves around in the hierarchy, this approach means that he will still be found.